# Spring Integration outbound-gateway with basic authentication

Tags: spring-integration

I have seen some examples , but i am unable to use that solutions

problem is that I have to pass basic authentication info as part of my config

current request below...can you tell me how to add basic authentication

```
<bean id="WSACaoedelen" class="nl.bIntnActiCallback">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://enst.nl/kkm/Kkmervice/toest"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="${KKSEURL}"></constructor-arg>
    </bean> 
    <int:chain input-channel="kkChannel" output-channel="dest-channel">
        <ws:header-enricher>       
            <ws:soap-action value="http://knst.nl/kkm/KkService/toest"/>
        </ws:header-enricher>           
        <ws:outbound-gateway uri="${GATEWAY}" request-callback="WSACaoedelen"/>
    </int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the *basic authentication* that it is a part of HTTP transport.

You need to consider to use a `HttpComponentsMessageSender` with an injected `setCredentials()`. In your case I guess you can just use `UsernamePasswordCredentials`:

```
<bean id="httpComponentsMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="credentials">
        <bean class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
            <constructor-arg value="userName"/>
            <constructor-arg value="password"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
...
<ws:outbound-gateway uri="${GATEWAY}" message-sender="httpComponentsMessageSender"/>
```

Comment: Answer works.Thanks. As we have encryption also, I need to use properties BSPWD=ENC(${BSPWD}) and jasypt beans.

Comment: Is it possible to enable pre emptive authentication using above?          Error:<faultcode>soapenv:Server.Transport.Http.401</faultcode><faultstring>1136 The HTTP Webservice returned an error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized</faultstring><faultactor>